# Azure Function / Typescript - Wait for function to complete processing each document

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, azure-functions, es6-promise

I have an Azure Function that inserts from JSON-LD into my GraphDB - however what I'm finding is my GraphDB keeps crashing, because the function is sending too many insert requests.

I've set `"maxConcurrentRequests": 1` and `"maxOutstandingRequests": 1` however it still doesn't seem to wait and process one at a time.

Could someone please explain why this so.

```
export async function onTrigger(context: Context, documents: Resource[] | null): Promise<void> {
    if (documents == null) { return }

    documents.forEach(async function (value: any) {

        if ("metadata" in value) {  } else { return; }

        let song: MyDocument = value.metadata.songs.song;

        // Create the JSON-LD object using the song object from above
        let jsonld = ...

        let nQuads = await jsonldParser.toRDF(jsonld, {format: 'application/n-quads'});

        let insertQuery = "INSERT DATA {" + nQuads + "}";

        try {
            let res = await axios.post('http://localhost:7200/mygraphdb', "update="+encodeURIComponent(insertQuery))
            if (res.status === 204) {
                console.log(`All Done!`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error! ${song.id}`);
        }


    });

}
```

Comment: I found adding this into my `host.json` helped - `"extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:01:00",
      "batchSize": 5,
      "maxDequeueCount": 0
    }
  }`
Guess I just had to set the maxPollingInterval.

Comment: And I placed this into function.json: `      "maxConcurrentRequests": 1,
      "maxOutstandingRequests": 1,
      "maxConcurrentCalls": 1,
      "maxItemsPerInvocation": 1,`

Comment: Although I'm not 100% what it is in these settings that makes it work - if someone could kindly let me know.

Comment: What kind of input binding are you using? If you could edit the question with the full function.json that would help a lot to figure out what is going on.